# Dynamic reference to Lua table method, param passed in is null

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm creating a dynamic table method reference and trying pass a single param to the method. The dynamic method reference does work and the table method is called just as expected, however the **completely not nil** param I'm passing to the method is nil inside the method. Can you point out my error in these 2 lines?...

Here is a small working example that demonstrates. On first line in the Consider:Move method, mons is nil

```
local Consider = {}
function Consider:Move( mons  ) 
    print( 'Mons ' .. mons.type .. ' considering Move...')
    actionChosen.score = 0
    return actionChosen
end

local mons = { type = 'Blue' }
local actionPref = 'Move'
local considerAction = Consider[actionPref]
print( 'MonsterAI:chooseAction mons: ', mons.type )
local actionTest = considerAction( mons )
```

Comment: Thanks for the down-vote. Please share why so I can correct my error in next post.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The issue is likely outside of these two lines (which appear to be correct). Also code [should be code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), not an image of said code.

Comment: @cfillion Thanks for sharing. I added a working example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: I've removed my downvote. The issue is that `Move` is defined using the `function someTable:fnName()` syntax, which is sugar for `function fnName(self, params)`. `mons` is accessible in `Move` as `self` currently and `mons` (which is actually the second argument) remains unset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions defined using the colon operator hides an additional first `self` argument. `function Consider:Move(mons)` is syntactic sugar for `function Consider.Move(self, mons)`.

Calling the function like `considerAction(mons)` sets the hidden `self` argument instead of the desired one.

You might want to pass the `Consider` table as `self`:

```
considerAction(Consider, mons)
```

Or, alternatively, define the function using the dot operator if you don't need `self`:

```
function Consider.Move(mons)
  print('Mons ' .. mons.type .. ' considering Move...')
end
```